# Deleting duplicate rows based on two columns excel

Tags: excel, multicol

I have two columns in a spreadsheet like so:

```
Col A: Col B:
00001  000000
00005  000001
       000005
....    .....
```

Basically what I want to to is have all of the unique values that appear only in Col B and not in Col A. Apparently there is a way to filter it, although I have no idea how that would work...

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You could use any one of a number of formula appraoches to do this. Eg: COUNTIF(), MATCH(), etc.

Comment: explore `VLOOKUP`; create a column C with results of a value from B looked up in A

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with an **Advanced Filter** - see screenshot, which reduces the list in column B to 00000, 00006.

[image]

I'll leave you to investigate the Advanced Filter feature though. It's on the Data tab (or menu in 2003).

If you are filtering the whole table though, rather than specifically column-B, then the option of *Unique records only* won't work/doesn't make sense.